# How to extract timeseries data from unspecified point

Tags: r

I was able to extract my data (temperature time-series) for a specific point (lat, lon) and now I want to do the same for a nearby point (without latitude and longitude) so I ran the following code:

```
ColLon <- which.min(abs(lon - gpoint$Lon[1]))
ColLat <- which.min(abs(lat - gpoint$Lat[1])) #my point

step <- 1

yy <- ColLat-step
xx <- ColLon-step

dd <- nc.get.var.subset.by.axes(cdf, var2read,axis.indices = list(X = xx,Y = yy))
```

but it keeps returning an error message:

```
Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset, : C function Rsx_nc4_get_var_int returned error
```

Comment: What error message is that?

Comment: Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,  : 
  C function Rsx_nc4_get_var_int returned error